# Json data format for telegraf and Influxdb

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, influxdb, telegraf

I have to process and store JSON data coming from Kafka into an InfluxDB bucket and I wanted to use the Telegraf connector to do so. However, I don't understand how to do so, given the odd structure of the JSON data. Below you find an example of such data:

```
{
    "v": "2.2",
    "r": [{
        "d": "IBA001",
        "u": "LowFrequencySampler",
        "s": [{
            "m": ["IRMS-AE-1", "IRMS-AE-2", "IRMS-AE-3", "IRMS-AE-4", "IRMS-AH-1", "IRMS-AH-2", "IRMS-AH-3", "IRMS-AH-4", "VRMS-AE-VT1", "VRMS-AE-VT2", "WATT-AE-1", "WATT-AE-2", "WATT-AE-3", "WATT-AE-4", "WATT-AH-1", "WATT-AH-2", "WATT-AH-3", "WATT-AH-4", "VAR-AE-1", "VAR-AE-2", "VAR-AE-3", "VAR-AE-4", "VAR-AH-1", "VAR-AH-2", "VAR-AH-3", "VAR-AH-4", "VA-AE-1", "VA-AE-2", "VA-AE-3", "VA-AE-4", "VA-AH-1", "VA-AH-2", "VA-AH-3", "VA-AH-4", "THD-AE-1", "THD-AE-2", "THD-AE-3", "THD-AE-4", "THD-AH-1", "THD-AH-2", "THD-AH-3", "THD-AH-4", "THD-AE-VT1", "THD-AE-VT2", "PF-AE-1", "PF-AE-2", "PF-AE-3", "PF-AE-4", "PF-AH-1", "PF-AH-2", "PF-AH-3", "PF-AH-4"],
            "t": "float",
            "s": {
                "@type": "array",
                "v": [
                    [20.18846, 21.02329, 33.39281, 20.41747, 4.764703, 4.472236, 0, 0, 25051.09, 25051.09, 322762.8, 342534.9, 656503.3, 336749, 95009.87, 92406.12, 0, 0, 389350.4, 400028.1, 518433.7, 384965, 72220.56, 63307.15, 0, 0, 505743, 526656.1, 836526.3, 511479.8, 119361, 112034.4, 0, 0, 6.514048, 6.288249, 7.584458, 6.183965, 14.40868, 15.38503, 0, 0, 1.644895, 1.639531, 0.6381919, 0.6503779, 0.7847961, 0.6583645, 0.7959343, 0.8248615, 0, 0]
                ],
                "t": ["2021-03-03T16:11:22.9511963Z"]
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

My goal is to "unpack" all the different elements of the array and link them to the device name and timestamp (that are single values) in order to obtain an output similar to this:

```
IBA001, IRMS-AE-1, 20.18846, 2021-03-03T16:11:22.9511963Z
IBA001, IRMS-AE-2, 21.02329, 2021-03-03T16:11:22.9511963Z
IBA001, IRMS-AE-3, 33.39281, 2021-03-03T16:11:22.9511963Z
...
```

How can I manage that? I really cannot understand how to configure the .config file in order to obtain such structure.

Any help is welcome, thanks!